# AppStoreConnectでdSYMをダウンロードが表示されない

Tags: xcode

リリースされているアプリのdSYMをダウンロードしたいのですが、
"dSYMをダウンロード"の表示がなくダウンロードできません。

[image: AppStoreConnectのスクリーンショット]

Xcode上の設定では以下設定になっております。
Debug Information Format -> ReleaseのみDWARF with dSYM File
Enable Bitcode -> false

Answer (score 0):

Bitcode対応のアプリだとリリースされてからAppleの方で新しくdSYMを作成するようでこの時に生成されたdSYMがあればダウンロードできるようになっていそう